# autoconf doesn't define prefix within AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I'm calling a sub-configure inside a AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS macro in my configure.ac, and I want to pass the sub-configure my prefix, etc dirs, but when I try to pass these variables, they aren't defined and the sub-configure just gets empty arguments.

Does anyone know how to pass these variables (or maybe there is a better way to run configure in a sub project)?

```
AC_INIT([admin-tools], [1.0])
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([.])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AX_PYTHON_DEVEL
AX_PKG_SWIG([], [], AC_MSG_ERROR([SWIG is required to build.]))
AX_SWIG_PYTHON
AC_PROG_CXX
AX_WITH_CURSES
AC_CONFIG_FILES([src/Makefile src/clients/Makefile])
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS([yast-core], [pushd src/yast-core; ./configure --prefix=${prefix} --libdir=${libdir}; popd])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Comment: Looks like I could do something with AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS

Answer (score 0):

I found AX_SUBDIRS_CONFIGURE, which allows me to run configure on a sub directory and customize the arguments passed to it. If you don't need custom args, you can use AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS.

Comment: `AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS` is the conventional way to set up subproject configuration.  Custom arguments do not present much problem here, as the top-level `configure` should pass them through even if it doesn't handle them itself.  The main vector for problems is if different component projects have *conflicting* requirements for arguments.

Comment: In my case, some of the subprojects are cmake projects (with a wrapper configure script), so I needed to customize a few of the parameters.

Comment: I also had to add some include/lib paths, since some of the projects expected some headers/libs to be installed, when actually they were in another subproject.